# resolve LateInitializationError: Field '_userBiodata@48229069' has not been initialized

Tags: flutter, dart, provider

I have a problem when I fetch data using provider in Flutter.

I've tried changing it to NULL (UserBiodata?) without using LATE but the error occurs again in other parts.

[image: Error]

Here is the code I wrote:

```
class UserBiodataProfile with ChangeNotifier {
  late UserBiodata _userBiodata;
  UserBiodata get userBiodata => _userBiodata;

  set userBiodata(UserBiodata newUserBiodata) {
    _userBiodata = newUserBiodata;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

I call the data here:

```
Text(
  userBiodataProvider.userBiodata.data.name,
  style: bold5,
),
```

How do I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While loding the data is null.

try this code

```
class UserBiodataProfile with ChangeNotifier {
  UserBiodata? _userBiodata;
  UserBiodata? get userBiodata => _userBiodata;

  set userBiodata(UserBiodata? newUserBiodata) {
    _userBiodata = newUserBiodata;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

---

```
Text(
userBiodataProvider.userBiodata == null ?  "" : 
userBiodataProvider.userBiodata.data.name,
style: bold5,
),
```

Comment: not working well on me

Comment: still with the same error

Comment: i think you got error from other code. Please cross check

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code:

```
final UserBiodata userBiodata = UserBiodata(
  status: …,
  code: …,
  data: …,
);
```

---

```
Text(
  userBiodata.data.name,
  style: bold5,
),
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250570/discussion-on-answer-by-my-car-resolve-lateinitializationerror-field-userbiod).